# Prevent HttpClient logging 404 errors in console

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am using HttpClient in client side blazor app, but when i am doing a call to an API that some times isnt there (because its an image search to an azure blob storage) it returns a 404 error which is fine. My issue is, is that the 404 error is then being displayed in the browser console (google chrome for me), is there a way of preventing this as i dont want the user to know it is a 404 instead i want to act upon that 404 my self by displaying a default image.

Here is my offending but simple code that then logs to the browser console.

```
await client.GetAsync("URL of Image");
```

Comment: Why do you care what appears in the console?  If users are looking at that, then they are already prepared to look at _anything_ you're doing.

Comment: @bobby, Please post your full component code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a bit more context and code examples? Are you handling the `HttpClient` errors in a `try/catch` block?

As far as I know, the browser will **always** log any 400-500 errors in the console, and you cannot disable this output. It's called the developer tools for a reason. Also, what is keeping users from viewing the network tab in those same tools?

I honestly think this is a non-issue unless you are naming files something suspicious..